# iPhone 6 went into 'find my iPhone mode' while in use

Tags: login

I was in the middle of texting my sister and my phone went into 'find my iPhone mode.' I did not activate it, was simply texting back and forth.

Comment: Does someone else have access to your Apple ID?  Parents perhaps?

Comment: Haha, my mother is 75 and doesn't live with me, so I'm pretty safe there!

Comment: That rules you your mother *only* and doesn't fully answer @bjbk's question.  What have you attempted to research (via your Apple acct)?  Have you contacted Apple?

Comment: I truly wasn't being snarky. I apologize if it appeared that way. To fully answer the question posed, no one else has access to my Apple ID. My sister and I were simply texting each other back and forth in quick succession, when suddenly, my text to her would not send. I tried to resend it 3 times, waiting a few minutes between attempts, with no success. While I was, literally, staring at my phone wondering what was going on, the screen popped up asking for passwords to both Apple ID and iTunes. It said I was required to connect to wifi and that I was unable to connect to my carrier (T-Mobile)

Comment: Though, the top of my screen showed that I was clearly connected to the carrier. I keep getting the message that find my iPhone had been activated. The screen color keeps showing up in either a light gray or purple, when the normal background color should be black. I don't run Facebook, Twitter, etc., nor any other apps that are potentially sketchy. I have neither added nor deleted any apps in over a year. Another message continues to pop up saying that the phone hasn't been backed up to iCloud in 55 weeks. I back up generally every 2 weeks, at minimum.